# Apply a specific class to the first item in a series with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a php script that echoes a series of uploaded images and I need to apply a class to the first image echoed in the series. Is this possible? For example, if I want to display 10 images and apply a class to only the first image, how would I go about it?

Here is the code, I am working with:

```
<div id="gallery">  
<?php
query_posts('cat=7');
while(have_posts())
{
the_post();
$image_tag = wp_get_post_image('return_html=true');
$resized_img = getphpthumburl($image_tag,'h=387&w=587&zc=1'); 
$url = get_permalink();
$Price ='Price'; 
$Location = 'Location';
$title = $post->post_title;
echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
echo "rel=\"<div class='gallery_title'><h2>";
echo $title;
echo "</h2></div>";
echo "<div class='pre_box'>Rate:</div><div class='entry'>\$";
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $Price, true);
echo "</div><div class='pre_box'>Location:</div><div class='entry'>";
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $Location, true);
echo "</div>\"";
echo  "'/></a>";
echo "";
}
?>
```

On line 13, the code looks like this:

```
echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
```

For the first item only, I need it to look like this:

```
echo "<a href='$url' class='show'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
```

EDIT:

So I have updated my code after reading everyones suggestions to look like this:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=7');
while(have_posts())
{
the_post();
$image_tag = wp_get_post_image('return_html=true');
$resized_img = getphpthumburl($image_tag,'h=387&w=587&zc=1'); 
$url = get_permalink();
$counter = 0;
$Price ='Price'; 
$Location = 'Location';
$title = $post->post_title;
while(have_posts())
{
    $counter++;
    if ($counter > 1) {
        echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='$url' class='show'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
    }
}
echo "rel=\"<div class='gallery_title'><h2>";
echo $title;
echo "</h2></div>";
echo "<div class='pre_box'>Rate:</div><div class='entry'>\$";
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $Price, true);
echo "</div><div class='pre_box'>Location:</div><div class='entry'>";
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $Location, true);
echo "</div>\"";
echo  "'/></a>";
echo "";
}
?>
```

Then my browser crashed, so I suspect I didn't put this together correctly....Any suggestions?

Comment: As I said below, you only need one `while(have_posts())` - remove the inner one, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Loop Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_counter) variable to count the iterations:

```
query_posts('cat=7');
$count = 0
while(have_posts())
```

Then, use it in your echo:

```
if ($count == 0){
   // echo with class
   echo "<a href='$url' class='show'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
}
else {
   // echo without class
   echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' "; 
}
```

Then at the bottom of your loop, make sure to increment it:

```
  echo "";
  $count = $count + 1;
}

?>
```

Comment: I updated, using the counter suggestions, but it seems to have thrown my site into some unending loop. See edit above -

Comment: Dude, you only need to have one `while(have_posts())` loop. Just delete the inner one (and its `{` and `}`) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a counter, to determine on which iteration you are :

```
$i_posts = 0;
query_posts('cat=7');
while(have_posts())
{
    if ($i_posts == 0) {
        echo "first iteration";
    }

    $i_posts++;
}
```

This means your line 13 would be replaced by something like this :

```
if ($i_posts == 0) {
    // First iteration of the loop : special class
    echo "<a href='$url' class='show'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
} else {
    // Next iterations : no special class
    echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$c = 0;
query_posts('cat=7');
while(have_posts())
{   
*** snip ***
if ($c == 0) {
  $class = " class='show'";
} else {
  $class = "";
}
echo "<a href='$url'$class><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
*** snip ***
$c++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter

```
$counter = 0;
while(have_posts())
{
    $counter++;
    if ($counter > 1) {
        echo "<a href='$url'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='$url' class='show'><img src='$resized_img' width='587' height='387' ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a boolean:

```
$firstTime = true;
while(have_posts())
{
    if($firstTime)
    {
        $firstTime = false;
        $class = 'class="show"';
    }
    else
    {
        $class = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a for loop instead of the while and add the class just during the first iteration.